# Does a SASS map has to be on one line?

Tags: dictionary, sass, syntax

I have this map in SCSS:

```
$headings: (
    'h1': (
        'size': 3.3125rem,
        'line-height': 1.15em
    ),
    'h2': (
        'size': 2.25rem,
        'line-height': 1.5em
    ),
    'h3': (
        'size': 1.5625rem,
        'line-height': 1.4em
    ),
);
```

I want to use it in my SASS code.
But to make the code work I have to remove the line breaks.

```
$headings: (h1: ('size': 3.3125rem, "line-height": 1.15em), h2: (size: 2.25rem, line-height: 1.5em), h3: ('size': 1.5625rem, 'line-height': 1.4em))
```

Multi-lines are not allowed in SASS maps, but aren't they though?
In my project I have much larger maps and this results in very long lines.

Whenever I google about this I find all kinds of SASS map examples, but they use SCSS instead.
A SASS languages but not .SASS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't multiline maps in the `.sass` format.

There's been an [open issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/216) on Github since 2011.

If you are using Webpack, there is a possible (temporary) workaround solution with [webpack-multiline-sass](https://github.com/wrwrwr/webpack-multiline-sass).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I will definitely check that package out.
I find this rather weird for such an established language haha.